# DllImport method isn't receiving data

Tags: c#, c++

```
BYTE* pImageBuffer = NULL;
    eResult res = PlayerLib::CreateImageSnapshot( iPlayerRef, eBMP, &pImageBuffer );
   if( res > 0 )
     { 
         ....                                    // do something with the image
          WriteFile(FileHandle, pBuffer, eRes, NULL, NULL);
          ReleaseImageSnapshot( pImageBuffer );   // free the image buffer in not longer needed!
     }
```

here i can receive the image data in pImageBuffer and i could do the some image process

the same way I have tryed in c# like

```
 [DllImport("PlayerLib")]
   public static extern int CreateImageSnapshot(int iPlayerRef, eImageFormat imgFormat,byte[] ppImageBuffer);


byte[] bte ;
CreateImageSnapshot(iPlayerref,eImageFormat.ePNG,bte);
```

here its giving some unhandeld Exception..... hopefully the problem is in byte[] but i can't point out...
please help me to overcome it.... thanks in advance

here it shoud return the imagedata in ppImageBuffer... but here it's giving zero byte only

Comment: can you paste exactly what exception is raised?

Comment: also at what line number

Comment: am receving zero byte of data only thats the problem

Comment: I don't know anything about the C# part, but you should definitely check the return value of WriteFile(), to check if it fails.

Comment: Without knowing what exception is thrown, its hard to guess what problem you're having.

Comment: in the C code, the last parameter to this function is BYTE **.  My guess is your dllimport hasn't properly expressed that the C# byte[] is passed by reference.

Comment: yes  asveikau thats the problem ,i don't know how to use BYTE** in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggest to you would be to marshal `BYTE **` as `ref IntPtr`.
Your declaration would be:

```
[DllImport("PlayerLib")]  
public static extern int CreateImageSnapshot(int iPlayerRef,
                         eImageFormat imgFormat, ref IntPtr ppImageBuffer);
```

P.S. and sorry for my English, guys ;)

Comment: k tror how can i call this function 
byte[] bte ; 
CreateImageSnapshot(iPlayerref,eImageFormat.ePNG,ref bte); is't correct

Comment: before you call this function you need to allocate some memory for buffer:  
int size = 10000;
int[] array = new int[size];
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem( Marshal.SizeOf(byte)* size);
Marshal.Copy(array, 0, buffer, size);

Comment: The CreateImageSnapshot function apparently allocates the memory, you don't have to do it yourself. So just use the Marshal.Copy call and remember to free the buffer with ReleaseImageShapshot.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that looks off to me is your C# declaration of CreateImageSnapshot.  Since your C++ code is correct, the third parameter must be a BYTE **.  But in C# you have the third parameter as a byte[] which feels like an incompatible type.